# Will these graphics cards work with my computer?

Tags: graphics-card

So I just got an off-lease PC off the internet and I'd like to get a new graphics card for it. I found a few on HP's website and I just want to know if these will be easy to install. Sort of "plug-and-play" if you will.

The specs are: AMD Athlon II X2 processor 3.0GHz, 8GB DDR3 SDRAM system memory, 320GB SATA hard drive, AMD Radeon HD 4200 Graphics, 240 W BTX power supply - Active PFC.

It seems that the graphics cards are quite specific for this model and according to their site, these cards are all supported: 
ATI Radeon HD 4550 (256MB DH) PCIe x16 Card
ATI Radeon HD 4650 (1GB DH) PCIe x16 Graphics Card
HP DisplayPort to VGA Adapter
HP DisplayPort to DVI-D Adapter
NVIDIA Quadro NVS 290 (256MB DH) PCIe x1 Graphics Card
NVIDIA Quadro NVS 290 (256MB DH) PCIe x16 Graphics Card

http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01865086 is the site I got this information from if it helps.

Comment: Check the power and cable requirements for each card.  PCI-e hardware is plug and play 99.98% of hardware on Windows is plug and play the technology is literally called "plug and play".  most of those cards won't result in any performance increases go to the next generation of cards if you want performance increases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the information on the link I can verify that the graphics cards listed will work. I have a small model HP a lot like the one you have (assuming the one you have is HP Compaq 6005 Pro Small Form Factor) and I can tell you that installation will be easy as long as you only get one of the listed cards, or another card with a small form factor compatibility. You'll just need to unplug from all power sources, pop the top off (or side depending on how it's standing), locate the PCI-E slot and plug it in.

Plug and play isn't exactly what I would call it. I have installed a few graphics cards in my day and I can say that Windows 7 does a really good job of getting drivers installed so yes it should work out of box with Windows 7 or 8, but it's been my experience that a good best practice is to go to the manufacturer website and download the latest drivers for your card anyway.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. You've answered everything I needed. As a followup to where you said "or another card with a small form factor compatibility", how do I know that other video cards have that? Will they list it in the specs?

Comment: It depends on the sender if they include the form factor compatibility. A really easy way to tell is to look at the video card itself. If it's smaller like this: http://www.amazon.com/Visiontek-Radeon-Graphics-RADEON-V-CARD/dp/B005UO4J5I that means it will most likely work, but the larger ones like this: http://www.amazon.com/EVGA-GeForce-SUPERCLOCKED-Graphics-02G-P4-2662-KR/dp/B00966IREK/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1430934264&sr=1-1&keywords=nvidia+660 will definitely not work due to size constraints with the case, and power constraints with the PSU among other things.

Comment: You can search around the model numbers to get the latest model numbers. Something like this might be pushing it, but should fit: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814196082&cm_re=AMD_Radeon_HD_8490-_-14-196-082-_-Product --- Also make sure to verify it includes the half height / low profile faceplate.

Answer (score 0):

The **ATI Radeon HD 4550** is the best all around card, from the list. It is 512 MB, uses the least power (20 watts) and generates -1/3 of the heat. It out performs the NVIDIA. You do not need to change the power supply. All of the cards on the list are specific for the HP 6005. The other responses are so not true. The HD 4550 is way better than the integrated graphics. Here is the user benchmark on Windows 7 64 Bit, 12 GB RAM and AMD Phenom II B95 X4 Quad Core-4 Thread 3.0 GHz:

AMD (Integrated) in fps:
Plane 2.1
Cube 3.9
Stones 1
Swarm 3.6
Galaxy 0.3
Sphere 2.3
**Total= 13.2**

AMD (ATI Radeon HD 45550) in fps:
Plane 5.2
Cube 7.2
Stones 4.4
Swarm 5.0
Galaxy 2.1
Sphere 3.4
**Total= 27.3**

All you have to do is insert the card and the computer will automatically install the driver, upon booting to Windows. Once you enter Windows, your CPU will scan your new hardware automatically and install the best driver. A pop-up will ask you to "Restart Computer Now." Click yes. That's it. You can go to device manager & double check, by updating driver.

You can choose the 1 GB video card or the 512 MB one. Use a low profile bracket or cut the full size one down.